# OpenShift Hazelcast

Tags: openshift, hazelcast

Is it possible to open a port for hazelcast on openshift? No matter what port I try, I get the same exception:

```
SocketException: Permission denied
```

I am not trying to open the port to the world. I just want to open a port so the gears can use Hazelcast. It seems like this should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably have to use a HTTP tunnel to connect Hazelcast, not a nice solution but I prototyped it some time ago: https://github.com/noctarius/https-tunnel-openshift-hazelcast

Anyhow gears should be openshift V2, isn't it? Never tried it with V2, if you get the chance, there's support for V3 (and V3.1) - http://blog.hazelcast.com/openshift/

Comment: Is it possible to use your SPI plugin for kubernetes?

https://github.com/noctarius/hazelcast-kubernetes-discovery

Comment: Yeah, that's what it is basically designed for, openshift just uses kubernetes itself.

Comment: I set up the discovery spi, but when I deploy it fails with:

FileNotFoundException: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

Comment: Do you know what could cause that? Here is the full stack trace:



Here is the full stack trace:


http://pastebin.com/EwT8JRS6

Comment: That looks helpful, you probably haven't configured it https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27973

Answer (score 1):

What cartridge type do you use?

You can bind to any port from 15000 to 35530 internally, but other gears won't be able to access it.

From my experience - I had to open the public proxy port for other members of the cluster to join.

For example, Vert.x cartridge uses Hazelcast for clustering and has some additional public proxy ports open (see https://github.com/vert-x/openshift-cartridge/blob/master/metadata/manifest.yml).

```
Endpoints:
  - Private-IP-Name:   IP
    Private-Port-Name: PORT
    Private-Port:      8080
    Public-Port-Name:  PROXY_PORT
    Mappings:
      - Frontend:      ""
        Backend:       ""
        Options:       { "websocket": 1}
  - Private-IP-Name:   IP
    Private-Port-Name: HAZELCAST_PORT
    Private-Port:      5701
    Public-Port-Name:  HAZELCAST_PROXY_PORT
  - Private-IP-Name:   IP
    Private-Port-Name: CLUSTER_PORT
    Private-Port:      9123
    Public-Port-Name:  CLUSTER_PROXY_PORT
```

(see https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/Cartridge_Specification_Guide/chap-Exposing_Services.html).

Comment: I'm using the WildFly Application Server 8.2.1.Final cartridge. https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-wildfly-cartridge/blob/master/metadata/manifest.yml This doesn't appear to have any extra ports that I can use. Would I have to deploy a custom cartridge?

Comment: I assume that OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_CLUSTER_PORT/OPENSHIFT_WILDFLY_CLUSTER_PROXY_PORT are already used by the cartridge itself? (You can check your ports status by executing `lsof` on your application gears).

I've ended up creating my own cartridge (forked from the Tomcat openshift cartridge source).

Comment: I'm a little late, but I was able to deploy a custom cartridge with the Hazelcast ports open. How did your nodes discover each other?

Comment: You have to use cartridge events to achieve this. VertX cartridge publishes and subscribes the "NET_TCP:vertx-cluster-info" event
(take a look at its mainfest.yml).
`publish-vertx-cluster` and `set-vertx-cluster` are just shell scripts in the hooks directory, that are run when a gear is added to an application.
The `publish` script writes the gear's public IP and the hazelcast proxy port to stdout, while the `set` script receives, joins the addresses and sets the OPENSHIFT_VERTX_HAZELCAST_CLUSTER variable containing the list of all application nodes. You can use it in your hazelcast.xml.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link to the custom cartridge you created?

Comment: Sure, here it is: (https://github.com/pi0tr/openshift-cartridge-jbossews)

It is forked from the JbossEWS (Tomcat) cartridge with some stuff added by me, based on the VertX cartdridge.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. When I deploy my custom cartridge, I added the new env variables to the manifest.yml exactly like you did:

- Private-IP-Name:   IP
  Private-Port-Name: HAZELCAST_PORT
  Private-Port:      5701
  Public-Port-Name:  HAZELCAST_PROXY_PORT

But when I start the cartridge, I get a permission denied error when the application tries to open port 5701. Did you have to take any additional steps to be able to open that port?

Comment: Is that error thrown by Hazelcast? Can you post a log with the detailed message?

Comment: I created a separate question for it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411032/openshift-v2-custom-cartridge-permission-denied-opening-port

Answer (score 0):

On OpenShift, you should only bind websockets to either port `8000` or `8443`.

See:

- https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html
- https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/